# How to move a sprite automatically using a physicsHandler in Andengine?

Tags: android, physics, sprites, movement, andengine

I use a `DigitalOnScreenControl` (knob with a four-directional arrow control) to move the entity and the entity which is bound to a `physicsHandler`.

```
physicsHandler.setEntity(sprite);
sprite.registerUpdateHandler(physicsHandler);
```

From the `DigitalOnScreenControl`, I know which direction I want my sprite to move. Inside its overridden `onControlChange` function, I call a function `animateSprite` that checks which direction I chose. Based on the direction, I animate my sprite differently.

**Problem:** I want to automatically move the sprite to a specific location on the scene, say at coordinates (207, 305). My sprite is at (100, 305, which means it has to move down by 107 pixels.

How do I tell the `physicsHandler` to move the sprite down by 107 pixels? My `animateSprite` method will take care of animating the sprite's downward motion.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you extend the PhysicsHandler class yourself and add automatic movement to the sprite then call the onUpdate(). For example :

```
public class Handler extends PhysicsHandler {

public Handler(IEntity pEntity) {
    super(pEntity);

}

@Override
protected void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed, IEntity pEntity) {
    // TODO move the pEntity down. eg: pEntity.sety(300)
    super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed, pEntity);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Box2D extension from AndEngine. [What you are looking for is `MouseJoint`](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082974). There is a working example of MouseJoint in the AndEngineExamples projects that you probably already have. [The class you are looking for is `PhysicsMouseJointExample`](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/cae0fa922a56ea542fe42904ea210e0e5852fb28/src/org/andengine/examples/PhysicsMouseJointExample.java).

MouseJoint is used to send the body in continuous movement to a target location. Basically you create MouseJoint as any other joint and then use its method `setTarget()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with andengine, but it uses box2d so there should be some method similar to:

```
PhysicsBody.setTransform(float x, float y, float angle)
```

Which sets the body's position to x, y and rotation to angle.

Comment: For a while, I tried to find a solution in this direction. I am able to setPosition(x,y), but then the sprite jumps. I need a smooth movement. (A bit like a ModeModifier will do.)

Answer (score 0):

Im using this listener to move my sprite around the screen.
The "*10" it's like the "velocity".

```
            @Override 
        public void onControlChange(final BaseOnScreenControl pBaseOnScreenControl, final float pValueX, final float pValueY) {
            playerBody.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(pValueX*10  , pValueY*10));
        }
```

Edit:
The listener is inside the ScreenControl instance.

Comment: Well this code snippet will not do what I want exactly. I cannot move the sprite from its current position (X,Y) (in pixels) to (X',Y') by supplying the values X'and Y' since I know them. Essentially, the sprite is bound to the DigitalOnScreenControl but I want to move it for the special case where the joystick should not be used to do that.